# What is the meaning of "We went to the aid of the stricken boat"?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

> We went to the aid of the stricken boat.

Does it mean "We come to rescue the stricken boat"?

I could not understand what is the "stricken boat" and "aid of" as I know it is an action but why it has "the" before aid? An act?

Comment: Where did you take this sentence? What are your thoughts concerning its meaning? Which part or parts are the hardest to understand?

Comment: This is in the Oxford Advanced's Learner Dictionary. Example of the word "stricken"

Comment: Basically, I could not understand what is the "stricken boat" and "aid of" as I know it is an action but why it has "the" before aid? An act?

Comment: *Aid* is both a verb and noun. In *We went to aid the stricken boat* it is a verb. In the dictionary's sentence, it is a noun

Comment: But Does the meaning change?

Answer (score 2):

It means they went to offer help to a vessel that was **incapacitated** and **could not function properly**. The implication is there was potential **danger to the passengers**.

**The** is used to make **aid** a **noun** i.e. **help** vs **the help**

> She walked with **the aid** of crutches.
>   She walked **aided** by crutches.
>
> She walked with **the help** of crutches.
>   She was **helped** by crutches.

Comment: So the "stricken boat" is a "vessel that was incapacitated and could not function properly"?

Comment: Yes, could be from any number of reasons. It does not necessarily mean the boat was **struck** by something

Comment: But why the sentence has "the" instead of "we went to aid the stricken boat"

Comment: I have added examples, **the** makes **aid** a noun which is then the object of the prepositional phrase **of the stricken boat**.